# Mongoose Express API not reading from req.body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I'm currently working on building out the backend for an app with MongoDB (Mongoose) and Express. I'm working on the API and noticed that while testing POST requests to `/movies` it does not submit any information from `req.body`. When I test it with dummy data and hardcode the information into the new movie that is to be submitted, it works, and that's the only data that is sent to the DB. Some code and examples are below:

Here is the code for the API route to `movies`, all found inside an `api.js` file.

```
router.get("/movies", (req, res, next) => {
  //this will return all the data, exposing only the id and action field to the client
  Movie.find({}, "movie")
    .then((data) => res.json(data))
    .catch(next);
});

router.post("/movies", (req, res, next) => {
  let movie = new Movie();
  movie.name = req.body.name;
  movie.description = req.body.description;
  movie.image = req.body.imageURL;
  movie.date = req.body.date;
  movie.runningTime = req.body.runningTime;
  movie.trailer = req.body.trailer;
  movie.cast = [];
  movie.rating = 0;
  movie.reviews = [];
  movie.meta = {
    likes: 0,
  };

  console.log(movie);

  movie.save((err, movie) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.status(201);
  });
});
```

Below is the Schema and model:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const movieSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  image: String,
  date: Date,
  runningTime: Number,
  trailer: String,
  cast: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'actor'}],
  rating: Number,
  reviews: [
    {
      author: String,
      title: String,
      text: String,
      rating: Number,
    },
  ],
  meta: {
    likes: Number,
  },
});

const Movie = mongoose.model("movie", movieSchema);

module.exports = Movie;
```

Example of what `movie` looks like after sending a POST request with all data filled:

```
{
  meta: { likes: 0 },
  cast: [],
  _id: 60d6e848d952c95f9ccd4dc8,
  reviews: [],
  rating: 0
}
```

Here is my `index.js` file:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const routes = require("./api/api");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Connect to DB
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log("Connection to DB was made"))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


// Header stuff makes configuration easier
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use("/api", routes);


app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err);
  next();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

None of the data submitted is from `req.body`, but is all hardcoded. I'm not too sure why nothing is being read from `req.body`, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You may want to include (in your post) the HTML form markup being used. Also, see this [Express - req.body](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) if youe missing anything.

Comment: A _body parser_ middleware is required in case of a POST request.

Comment: currently, you're using express.json() middleware to parse incoming requests. So, requests should be in JSON format otherwise req.body won't be populated.

Answer (score 0):

You have your parser in place, so that should be fine. Please make sure your request is proper JSON. (the client or cURL req code would be welcome). I recommend using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to test HTTP endpoints.

I recommend you use a custom middleware with the [`Joi`](https://joi.dev/) validation module to prevent any errors from happening. Here's my take on it (it's TypeScript)

```
import Joi, { ObjectSchema } from "joi";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

export function validate(schema: ObjectSchema): (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => unknown {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        const validation = schema.validate(req.body);
        const error = !!validation.error;
        if (error) return res.status(400).json({ code: "INVALID_BODY" });
        return next();
    };
}
```

To use like that:

```
router.get("/path", 
  validate(Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required()
    // ...
  })),
  async (req, res) => {
    // Your handler
  }
)
```

As for the rest, allow me to give you some suggestions.

1. According to the [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), you should be using find with promises like that `await Model.find().exec()` instead of `await Model.find()`.
2. You should use Mongoose's [default values](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html) to avoid repetition!
3. Instead of assigning each property of a new object like that, try:

```js
const movie = new Movie({
  name: req.body.name,
  description: req.body.description,
  // ...
})
```